# AngularJS Material tables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

Our team is using AngularJS Material (https://material.angularjs.org/), and need to create a couple tables.  It doesn't look like that library has tables...which is pretty odd.  Just wanted to check that we're not overlooking something.  If it doesn't include tables, is there a preferred library for generating Material tables?

Comment: It doesn't. We used https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table

Comment: thanks for verifying @Ronnie and for the suggestion!

Comment: I would second Ronnie's suggestion. We used it in production at my last client.